# I entered the wrong GitLab credentials in the command line. How do I change them?

Tags: git, command-line, gitlab

I was trying to connect to my company's GitLab through command line so I could clone a project. I entered the wrong credentials and now I can't figure out how to change them.

Because this is a work computer, I don't have access to the Credentials Manager. I have to do it through command line.

I'm on a Window machine and using wincred.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: What credential manager are you using?  `git config credential.helper` should tell you.

Comment: I'm using a Windows machine

Comment: I'm using wincred